# Accessibility not reading screen in Android

Tags: android, user-interface, accessibility

When opening a new activity and the accessibility enabled, no element is being read automatically but when clicking on the texts the voice is reading out the content. Is it there something that I may be missing?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by adding this.

android:importantForAccessibility="yes"

for some reason no elements on the screen were being read automatically as it always happens